# Nodejs (Express) connecting MySQL - Local and Remote connection different?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

guys. I am learning how to use **Express to connect to remote MySQL**. So, I started out doing it on my local machine (a local MySQL server). After I have **succeeded on the local environment**, I tried changing the the connection to a remote MySQL hosting (at DB4Free). Yes, I have **succeeded on the localhost**. However, whenever I **run a Get/Post to the remote MySQL Server**, my console show me the **error** below. I'll attach the related segment of codes below here. I have been trying it the whole afternoon.
Hope that someone here can enlighten on this matter. Thank you in advance guys :)

> This is the error shown in my console

[image]

> My file for connecting db is as below - ConnectionString.js

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var pool = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 100,
        host     : '85.10.205.173:3306',
        user     : '******* ',
        password : '*******',
        database : '*******',
    });

exports.getConnection = function(callback) {
  pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    if(err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    callback(err, conn);
  });
};
```

> Portion of my file for the routes and query is this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var conn = require('../database/ConnectionString');

var result;

//Validate user login
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {

        conn.getConnection(
            function (err, client) {

                client.query('SELECT * FROM mt_User', function(err, rows) {
                    // And done with the connection.
                    if(err){
                        console.log('Query Error');
                    }

                    res.json(rows);
                    client.release();

                    // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
                });

        });     

});
```

Comment: Did you test if you can access mysql (the remote one) from the command line?

Comment: No but I have tested it using php codes instead. It works fine with the same set of connection strings

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Alright, I have found the issue. It seems that the mysql package in npm requires that the **host and port to be defined separately**. After tuning it to this code below for my ConnectionString.js file. It finally works.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var pool = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 100,
        host     : '85.10.205.173',
        port     :  3306,
        user     : '*******',
        password : '*******',
        database : '*******',
    });

exports.getConnection = function(callback) {
  pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    if(err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    callback(err, conn);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you man you made my day, I was struggling for day and finally I reached out your answer and found the solution here

Comment: Glad that it helps!

Comment: @I have one more question can help me ?