# PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST error when connecting to mysql PHPMyAdmin from nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, vps

PHPMyAdmin is running on a VPS at http://ip_address:port_number. When trying to connect from a Nodejs app, I am getting the error: 'Connection lost: The server closed the connection'.

Here's the code snippet:-

```
const express = require('express');
// const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// MySQL
const connection = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 1000,
  connectTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  acquireTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  timeout         : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  host            : 'ip_address', 
  user            : 'root',
  password        : 'password', 
  database        : 'customers',
  port            : port_number,
  multipleStatements: true
});


// Listen on environment port of 5000
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${port}`)
});

// Get all data
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  let sql = `SELECT * FROM customers_data LIMIT 50`;
  connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log('err', err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('connection established: ', results);
  });

});
```

System: Windows 10,
MySQL version: 2.18.1 (latest),
Nodejs version: 14.17.1

Comment: First of all PHPMyAdmin is an application that displays the actual data in the database, you should not try and connect to it but rather to the actual sql server...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039929/nodejs-express-connecting-mysql-local-and-remote-connection-different

Comment: We are using SSD nodes and they have provided us with an IP for our server. The PHP Myadmin is available at this same IP. Should I write ssdnodes in host?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to connect hopefully it will work

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'database name'
});
connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected!');
});
```

Comment: Why are you writing 'localhost' in host? This https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql mentions `host: The hostname of the database you are connecting to. (Default: localhost)` My database is not on localhost.

Comment: The error I am getting is `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`